# Next.js V13 simply not working and I'm stuck

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I started recreate a react app in next.js and everything was going well, until i ran into an error which said:

Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

I couldn't fix it, so i removed everything until it was back to the start and it still didn't work, so I create a new app and I still get the same error.

I am trying re installing next but still the same.

I am now stuck and would appriciate any suggestions.

(is there a way I can just remove next.js and re install?)

Comment: Please add more details. Can you upload the code to a public repo and post the link? It's really hard to suggest anything based on these info.

Comment: literally if I create next app using any of the guide npm instructions i have the same issue, this is before i make any modifications.

Comment: I have removed next and re installed it and it seems to have fixed it.